# How can I read and edit the contents of a file.txt in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have this txt :

```
(FIEC01552 LENGUAJES DE PROGRAMACION 40)

(FIEC06411 COMPUTACION Y SOCIEDAD 39)

(FIEC03459 INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL 40)

(ICM01974 ECUACIONES 40)

(ICM00604  ALGEBRA 40)
```

so I wanted edit or eliminate one of them so my file txt would look like

```
(FIEC01552 CALCULO INTEGRAL 30)

(FIEC06411 COMPUTACION Y SOCIEDAD 39)

(ICM01974 ECUACIONES 40)

(ICM00604  ALGEBRA 40)
```

In this moment just have read a file with this code

```
(let ((in (open "/tmp/materias.txt" :if-does-not-exist nil)))
    (when in
        (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
        while line do (format t "~a~%" line))
    (close in)
    )
)
```

at the moment I 'm using clips in windows for this project

Comment: format your question properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to use the functions open and close yourself. There is [with-open-file](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_with-open-file.html) which will allow us to open the file, and will automatically close it for us when we are done with it. So now that we can open the file, how can we extract the data from it? Well the data is stored as lists, so we can use the function [read](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_readcm_re_g-whitespace.html) which reads in Lisp data structures (in this case lists). So now lets write a function that will read in all of the data in the file.

```
(defun read-input (file)
  "Return a list containing all of the data that is in the file."
  (with-open-file (in file :direction :input)
    (loop for exp = (read in nil nil) ; Read an expression, if the file is empty
          while exp                   ; exp will be nil, so the while will fail.
          collect exp)))              ; Collect the data into a list.
```

Now that we can read in all of the data, we have to eliminate the data that we do not want. Say we have a predicate 'unwanted', which returns true on any piece of data that we want to remove. We can then use the function [remove-if](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html) which will take a predicate and a list, and will remove all of the elements in the list that satisfy the predicate. So now lets write a function that will do it.

```
(defun eliminate-unwanted-data (data-list)
  "Remove all of the unwanted data from DATA-LIST."
  (remove-if #'unwanted data-list))
```

If you want to edit the data, you are going to have to use a function 'edit-data' that uses something like mapcar, which applies a function to each element of the list. Then all you have to do is write a separate function 'convert-data', which will take a single piece of data and convert it into whatever new data that you want.

So we can now read the data in, and remove all of the unwanted data. All that's left is to write it back into a file. We can use with-open-file again since it allows us to open both input and output files.

```
(defun write-output (data-list file)
  "Write the data out to the file."
  (with-open-file (out file :direction :output
                            ;; We want to replace the file if it already exists.
                            :if-exists :supersede) 
    (loop for data in data-list  ; For each piece of data,
          do (print data out)))) ; print it to the file.
```

So now that we have functions that do all of the pieces that we want, what's left is to chain them together.

```
(defun run (in-file out-file)
  "Do the whole thing."
  (write-output (eliminate-unwanted-data (read-input in-file))
                out-file))
```

And we are done! All that's left is to call run with the files we want to use (they can also be the same file).

```
(run "input-file" "output-file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire file as a list of s-exprs. Process that list (e.g. by removing/replacing some s-exprs). Write that list entirely into the file again.

Comment: but how put a condition that make that because is a litle confusing make a list and put each word inside the list